# Spring boot: Getting 404 status always

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to setup Spring boot basic example in my machine. BUt after setup, i am getting 404 status code returned.

I tried so many solutions provided on stack overflow. But none of them resolved my problem. Please help me, TIA.

I tried sub package structure to main mathod present package.
I tried adding scanBasePackages to @SpringBootApplication. Still no luck.

my code: Main Class . I tried by using without and with scanBasePackages.

```
package com.online.sbo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages  = {"com.online.sbo"})
public class OnlineSboApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OnlineSboApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller: In server logs its not showing that this controller is registerd.

```
package com.online.sbo;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping(value="/render", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String renderHomre() {
        return "gfvbytfgh";
    }    
}
```

My Pom.xml: I have not added any security in my project. I have created this project from start.spring.iosite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.online.sbo</groupId>
    <artifactId>OnlineSbo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>OnlineSbo</name>
    <description>Odisha Bank</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application.properties:- There is No entry in this file.

Answer (score 0):

You use @RestController attribute wrong.
This should work:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
     @GetMapping(value="/render", produces =
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String renderHomre() {
    return "gfvbytfgh";
}
}
```

ps: In your example `localhost:8080/render` should work, too.